# найти разницу в датах при группировке по одному клиенту

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица, в котрой есть столбец id. По каждому клиенут есть несколько дат платежей, например он платил 4-3 раза. Нужно найти разницу между этими платежами (pay_date) по каждому клиенту и сделать отдельный столбец. То есть не общую разницу найти, между первой и последней датой. А между первой и последующей датой и так далее, в рамках каждого клиента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
idx = df.reset_index().groupby(['id'])["index"].last().to_numpy()

df['life_time'] = df.groupby(['id'])['pay_date'].diff()

df.loc[idx, "life_time"] = df.loc[idx, "life_time"].combine_first(df.loc[idx, "pay_date"])
```

Далаю так, как показано на коде, и получается что дата просто переносится со столбца дата платежа, в новый столбец.

Вот здесь представлен один клиент,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В крайнем правом столбце, его платежи по датам, соответственно надо найти разницу между датами. И так по каждому клиенту.

Comment: _"Нужно найти разницу между этими платежами"_ уточните между чем и чем необходимо найти разницу, а еще лучше приведите пример того, что должно получиться в результате

Comment: Вот например есть клиент, и нужно найти разницу между каждой последующей датой (столбец pay_date) и занести эти значения в отдельный столбец по соответствующей строке. добавила описание с скриншотом.

Comment: зачем вы добавляете скриншоты? добавьте текстом.

Answer (score 0):

не уверен что до конца понял ваши пожелания, попробуйте такой вариант (по понятным причинам этот код не тестировался):

```
df['life_time'] = df.groupby('id')['pay_date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=0)).cumsum())
```

предполагается что `pay_date` имеет тип Datetime

Comment: я вот было сделал подобное, но получится каша при приведении к исходным индексам. фрейм по-любому надо разбивать по клиентам, сортировать и потом уже делать diff, как мне кажется.

Comment: @strawdog да про сортировку я не подумал, может получиться "каша"

Comment: @SergFSM
 Спасибо, так то работает, считает и записывает в столбец. Но да, нужна сортировка. Буду крутить ещё.